# QListWidget moving to end of list automatically

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a `QListWidget` that has many items added to it, however i want the `QListWidget` to auto-scroll to the last item everytime a new item is added to it.Is this even possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`listWidget->scrollToBottom()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scrollToBottom) would work

Comment: Could you conditionally `scrollToBottom()` only if it is currently at the bottom?

Comment: You can check that by accessing scrollbar widget: `scrollbar = myListView.verticalScrollBar(); if(scrollbar == NULL || scrollbar.value() == scrollbar.maximum()) { addItem(); myListView.scrollToBottom(); } else { addItem(); }` Here we check if scrollbar exists at all (just to be safe), and if it is missing *or* we are already at bottom then we do scroll after adding item. Otherwise we just add item without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Should work with [scrollToItem()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#scrollToItem).

Answer (score 0):

try the scrollTo method  inherited from QAbstractItemView http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo

Comment: This won't work for the item you have just added. Or more precisely, it won't work reliably. Often by the time you added a new item, the list view does not yet know about its presence and hence cannot scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to use Qt's signal/slot mechanism:

```
connect(listWidget->model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)),
        listWidget, SLOT(scrollToBottom()));
```

via https://forum.qt.io/topic/1770/qlistwidget-auto-scroll/4